# Move bootstrap grid items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Let's say we have two bootstrap sections. First one has logo in it. Second one is divided to another two bootstrap sections. Just like this..

```
<div class="col-md-3">
 <img src="logo.png">
</div>

<div class="col-md-9">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-marker"></i>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-12">
  //Navbar
 </div>
</div>
```

Now my client is requesting to add the font awesome font section shows in navigation area on mobile view behind nav links. Please see Screenshot. Social icons placed in another div section. So I can't move it to nav links. But I tried with media quarries this way. Add social icons as nav link. Hide it on normal screen, Shows it on mobile view. Is that the legit way to achieve my requirement?

[image]

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You also forgot to include your screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hide it on normal screen, Shows it on mobile view. Is that the legit
>   way to achieve my requirement?

Have a look at the responsive utilities section on the getbootstrap website

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

You can use classes to show / hide elements depending on screen size. In your case you would have your social icons in a div with hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg classes.

```
<div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"></div>
```

Any elements in this div are hidden until the screen is at it's smallest, suitable for smart phones.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Bootstrap classes:

```
.hidden-sm 
.hidden-md
.hidden-lg
```

Will hide on those media queries, you can also use .visible-* (* - sm, md, lg) which is the opposite.

On a side note, I would suggest to use rows to separate your columns:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <img src="logo.png">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-marker"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                //Navbar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Stays inline with Bootstrap :)